# my python code is not working as intended and returns wrong outputs

Tags: python

```
dacommandos = '!help'

actiontaken = input('what do you want to do: ')

if actiontaken == 'help':
    print(dacommandos)
else:
    print('no')
```

Whenever I type in 'help' it returns 'no', and whenever I type anything else it returns and error with *input* is not defined.

Comment: In my case, I did not encounter problems as you stated. The code works fine for "help" and for any other strings it prints "no".

Comment: Are you using Python 2? `help` is a built-in function; any other input is likely an undefined variable. Use `raw_input` instead (or stop using Python 2 and switch to Python 3).

Comment: I tried your code and works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be running this in the interpreter. So go to a command line and type in python. Then you'll see >>> which means you are in the interpreter.

Then type each command as follows:

```
>>> dacommandos = '!help'
>>> actiontaken = input('what do you want to do: ')
what do you want to do: help
>>> if actiontaken == 'help':
...     print(dacommandos)
... else:
...     print('no')
... 
!help
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be correct, you might have typed `!help` instead of `help`.

Answer (score 0):

Your system might be including the terminal return in the string. Try printing out actiontaken to see what’s in it as well as the length of the string. Be careful on indentation using tabs vs spaces. You might end up testing the first four characters in actiontaken == ‘help’.